# What is the role of `i` in `.each(function (i) {})`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, api

http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Nb/

hello, its simple example from jQuery documentation and i'm wondering why there is

```
  $(document.body).click(function () {
      $( "div" ).each(function (i) {
        if ( this.style.color != "blue" ) {
          this.style.color = "blue";
        } else {
          this.style.color = "";
        }
      });
    });
```

why there is function(i)? It equels to function() and makes  no diference when exectued.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.each` takes a function with 2 arguments: the index and the current element. But also `this` is pointing to the current element. So this could could also be written as:

```
$("div").each(function (index, element) {
    if (element.style.color != "blue") {
        element.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
        element.style.color = "";
    }
});
```

Since in this example the arguments are not used you could omit them. Javascript allows you to do that.

So basically if you don't need the index inside the function it is just shorter to write:

```
$("div").each(function () {
    if (this.style.color != "blue") {
        this.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
        this.style.color = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: ... and you can find stuff like that by reading the jQuery documentation.  All you have to do is google [_jquery each_](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), where you can read: "_In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time..._"

Comment: isn't it like (this) is much more clear then indexes and has no disadvantages?

Comment: @FilipBartuzi - Also from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/): "_The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.)..._"  There are times when you just want a string in stead of an object.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the index of the object that you are looping thorugh...`$.each` has two optional arguments index and value. in your case , you are assiging the optional arguments but not using it.. since `this` also points to the current looping element .. you can just omit the `i`

```
$( "div" ).each(function () {
   ...
```

and code will work..